# Changing values inside my GridView on load with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that gets populated with data from a SQL database, very easy.
Now i want to replace values in my one column like so......

If c04_oprogrs value is a 1 then display **Take** in the GridView.

If c04_oprogrs value is 2 then display **Available** in the GridView.

What code changes must i make to change to my code to display the new values.

My Grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                Height="281px" Width="940px" 
                Font-Size="X-Small" AllowPaging="True" 
                onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_oprogrs" HeaderText="Order Progress" 
                        SortExpression="c04_oprogrs" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_orderno" HeaderText="Order No." 
                        SortExpression="c04_orderno" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_orddate" HeaderText="Date of Order" 
                        SortExpression="c04_orddate" DataFormatString="{0:d/MM/yyyy}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_ordval" HeaderText="Order Value" 
                        SortExpression="c04_ordval" DataFormatString="{0:R#,###,###.00}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_delval" HeaderText="Delivered Value" 
                        SortExpression="c04_delval" DataFormatString="{0:R#,###,###.00}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_invval" HeaderText="Invoice Value" 
                        SortExpression="c04_invval" DataFormatString="{0:R#,###,###.00}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c04_orddesc" HeaderText="Order Description" 
                        SortExpression="c04_orddesc" >
                        <ControlStyle Width="300px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My Page load

```
SqlConnection myConnection;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;

        //making my connection
        myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SAMRASConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select TOP 40 c04_credno, c04_orderno, c04_orddate, c04_ordval, c04_delval, c04_invval, c04_oprogrs, c04_orddesc FROM C04ORDS WHERE c04_credno = '" + Session["CreditorNumber"] + "'AND c04_oprogrs <> 9 ORDER BY c04_orddate DESC", myConnection);

        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "MyData");

        GridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
        Session["DataSource"] = dataSet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Etienne

**EDIT:**

*MY FINAL SOLUTION*

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Find the value in the c04_oprogrs column. You'll have to use

            string value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

            if (value == "1")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Take";
            }
            else if (value == "2")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Available";
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event for this. Using this event you can alter the content of specific columns before the grid is rendered.

To clarify a little. First you add a template column with a label to your grid view (see also the answer by ranomore):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Next you implement the `RowDataBound` event (I haven't checked the code below, so it may contain some syntax errors):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Find the value in the c04_oprogrs column. You'll have to use
        // some trial and error here to find the right control. The line
        // below may provide the desired value but I'm not entirely sure.
        string value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

        // Next find the label in the template field.
        Label myLabel = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("myLabel");
        if (value == "1")
        {
            myLabel.Text = "Take";
        }
        else if (value == "2")
        {
            myLabel.Text = "Available";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example please?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i made some changes and it worked!! COOL!!

Comment: tanx for ur smart answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a template column and call a function in your code behind.

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#FieldDisplay(Eval("c04_oprogrs")) %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

then in your code behind do

```
protected string FieldDisplay(int c04_oprogrs)
{
 string rtn = "DefaultValue";
 if (c04_oprogrs == 1)
 {
    rtn = "Take";
 }
 else if (c04_oprogrs == 2)
 {
    rtn = "Available";
 }
 return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using a function.  The ternary statement is in VB. If you have to nest another ternary statement to really test for 2 then it'd be easier to go with rwwilden's solution.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Progress" SortExpression="c04_oprogrs" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# IIF(CInt(Eval("c04_oprogrs")) = 1, "Take", "Available") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a field in the SQL Statement

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select TOP 40 c04_credno, c04_orderno, c04_orddate,  
c04_ordval, c04_delval, c04_invval, c04_oprogrs, c04_orddesc ,  
CASE c04_oprogrs WHEN 1 THEN "Take" WHEN 2 THEN "Available" ELSE "DontKnow" END AS  
Status FROM C04ORDS WHERE c04_credno = '" + Session["CreditorNumber"] + "'AND  
c04_oprogrs  9 ORDER BY c04_orddate DESC", myConnection);
```

And make that new field part of the BoundColumn in the markup.
Pardon my SQL syntax but I hope you get the idea.

EDIT: Do not use the syntax  `= '" + Session["CreditorNumber"] + "'`.
See sql injection attack and how to avoid it using parameterized SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it did work after i fixed some syntax. But i went with another option above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best efficient way.
Make a case in sql server view, like :-

```
select case <columnname> 
       when 1 then 'available' 
       when 0 then 'not available' 
       end as <columnname> 
from <tablename>
```